# Why does this function create so many normals for a rectangle? Shouldn't they only have 4?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

I have a function which calculates the nearest normal to a point on a rectangle.

That is, if you place a point, the function will return the location of the nearest point on the rectangle, along with the direction of the normal at that point.

The function which does this seems to work, except at the corners it calculates many more normals. But I just desire to have the 4. Is there any way I can refactor this function to only produce the proper four normals? And is it an error for it to be returning anything more than 4? Or mathematically is it okay for a rectangle to have more than 4 normals?

Here's an entire duplication of the issue. You can click your mouse around to draw the normal automatically to that point:

```js
class Vec2 {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;  
  }

    magnitude() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  }

  direction(x, y) {
    return new Vec2(x - this.x, y - this.y).normalize();
  }

  normalize() {
    let magnitude = this.magnitude();

    if (magnitude !== 0) {
      return new Vec2(this.x / magnitude, this.y / magnitude);
    }

    return this;
  }
}

class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, a) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
    this.w = w; this.h = h;
    this.a = a;
  }
}

class Line {
  constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1; this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2; this.y2 = y2;
  }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawCircle(c, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color || "#000";
  ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function rotateCanvas(x, y, a) {
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(a);
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);
}

function drawRectangle(r) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  rotateCanvas(r.x + r.w / 2, r.y + r.h / 2, r.a);
  ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
  rotateCanvas(r.x + r.w / 2, r.y + r.h / 2, -r.a);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawLine(line, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color || "#000";
  ctx.moveTo(line.x1, line.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(line.x2, line.y2);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function getCollisionNormal(cX, cY, rX, rY, rW, rH, rA) {
  const eX = rW / 2;
  const eY = rH / 2;

  const rCX = rX + eX;
  const rCY = rY + eY;

  const uxX = Math.cos(rA);
  const uxY = Math.sin(rA);

  const uyX = Math.cos(rA - 1.571)
  const uyY = Math.sin(rA - 1.571);

  const distanceX = cX - rCX;
  const distanceY = cY - rCY;

  let dx = distanceX * uxX + distanceY * uxY;
  if (dx > eX)  { dx = eX; }
  if (dx < -eX) { dx = -eX; }

  let dy = distanceX * uyX + distanceY * uyY;
  if (dy > eY)  { dy = eY; }
  if (dy < -eY) { dy = -eY; }

  const pX = rCX + dx * uxX + dy * uyX;
  const pY = rCY + dx * uxY + dy * uyY;

  const deltaX = cX - pX;
  const deltaY = cY - pY;
  
  const magnitude = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);

  if (magnitude === 0) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0, xDir: 0, yDir: 0 };
  } else {
    return { x: pX, y: pY, xDir: deltaX / magnitude, yDir: deltaY / magnitude };
  }
}

let r1 = new Rectangle(50, 150, 300, 200, 1.67);
let r2 = new Rectangle(300, 100, 1, 1);

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  drawRectangle(r1);

  const norm = getCollisionNormal(r2.x, r2.y, r1.x, r1.y, r1.w, r1.h, r1.a);

  const rCX = r1.x + r1.w / 2;
  const rCY = r1.y + r1.h / 2;

  const line = new Line(r2.x, r2.y, rCX, rCY);
  const dir = new Vec2(r2.x, r2.y).direction(rCX, rCY);

  drawLine(new Line(norm.x, norm.y, norm.x + norm.xDir * 50, norm.y + norm.yDir * 50), "#ff0000");

  requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(redraw);

canvas.addEventListener("pointermove", e => {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) { return; }

  r2.x = e.clientX;
  r2.y = e.clientY;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

The function in question is `getCollisionNormal`.

Comment: Think about it mathematically: what does a normal vector look like at the corner of a rectangle?

Comment: @Pointy I understand the logic, but _should_ a rectangle indeed have more than just 4? I thought it was defined as having 4. Is there any way to clamp it to 4, because I _think_ for the purposes of my application the corners are messing up due to this.

Comment: A corner is not differentiable; the concept of a normal doesn't really make sense at those anomalous points. Along the sides of the rectangle, all the normals are (essentially) the same for each, and so yes there are four. However, I'm no mathematician; I'm just remembering high school stuff and that was an embarrassingly long time ago.

Comment: Yeah, so, can I clamp it somehow? To fix it?